# Google API JSON Postal Code with PHP in Address Object

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

I want go get the adress details from a JSON return like:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

But the Array always differs in the amount of elements. So any Idea how to get the adress details like postal code with php?

Comment: Iterate through the array, looking for types='postal_code', but I would start with the last element and work up to find it more quickly.

Comment: or even http://www.mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you if you want to retrieve the postal_code. It should give you the idea of how to access the other data you require:

```
// Decode json
$decoded_json = json_decode($json);

foreach($decoded_json->results as $results)
{

    foreach($results->address_components as $address_components)
    {
        // Check types is set then get first element (may want to loop through this to be safe,
        // rather than getting the first element all the time)
        if(isset($address_components->types) && $address_components->types[0] == 'postal_code')
        {
                    // Do what you want with data here
            echo $address_components->long_name;            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little addition to the answer provided by **Springie**. If you want to loop through the whole array, you'll need to add another condition, because you might end up with getting only prefix of the post code.

```
if ( isset($address_components->types) 
    && $address_components->types[0] === 'postal_code'
    && !in_array('postal_code_prefix', $address_components->types) ) { }
```